# Multiple matches in hash table

Tags: ruby, parsing, duplicates

Learning Ruby (v. 2.5) in coursera.
Aim is to write on ruby simple parser, which will count what IP host is responsible for the most queries in the apache logs.

Apache logs:

```
    87.99.82.183 - - [01/Feb/2018:18:50:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "http://35.225.14.147/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
    87.99.82.183 - - [01/Feb/2018:18:50:52 +0000] "GET /secret.html HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
```

Ruby code:

```
    class ApacheLogAnalyzer

      def initialize
        @total_hits_by_ip = {}
      end

      def analyze(file_name)
        ip_regex = /^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}/
        file = File.open(file_name , "r")
        file.each_line do |line|
          count_hits(ip_regex.match(line))
        end
      end

      def count_hits(ip)
        if ip
          if @total_hits_by_ip[ip]
            @total_hits_by_ip[ip] += 1
          else
            @total_hits_by_ip[ip] = 1
          end
        end
      end
```

Result is following:

```
      {#<MatchData "87.99.82.183">=>1, #<MatchData "87.99.82.183">=>1}
```

The result contains duplicates (it shoud contain one key "87.99.82.183" with value 2). Where could be the issue?

Comment: What's the problem, the question?

Comment: It would be helpful if you demonstrate what *has to be* vs *what is* along with the effort undertaken - otherwise the question causes confusion and is not answered efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The result contains duplicates in your case because hash keys are different objects but with the same values. Look at this examples:

```
a = "hello world foo".match(/he/) # => #<MatchData "he">
b = "hello world bar".match(/he/) # => #<MatchData "he">
a == b # => false
```

You can replace the hash keys with just string for example to definitely avoid this:

```
class ApacheLogAnalyzer
  def analyze(file_name)
    File.open(file_name).each_line.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |result, line|
      ip = line.split
      hash[ip] += 1
      result
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. I found that using method to_s resolves the issue.
So improved code looks like this:

```
 count_hits(ip_regex.match(line).to_s)
```